# Autoform + Collection 2

Tags: meteor

Hi I have a problem with error population on client side. 
Client/html

```
 <template name="add_book">    
 {{#autoForm collection="booklist" id="insertBooklist" type="insert"}}
 <div class="forms">

 {{>afFieldLabel name="title"}}

 {{> afFieldInput name='title' autofocus='' placeholder="schemaLabel" class="input-text"}}

 {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='title' autoform=..}}
  <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name='title' autoform=..}}}</span>
 {{/if}}
 </div>
   <a href="{{pathFor 'user_board'}}" class="butyellow"><span>Save</span></a>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

As client JS I have next:

```
AutoForm.setDefaultTemplate('plain');

Template.add_book.events({
  'click .butyellow': function (event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      title = template.find("input:text[name=\"title\"]");

      var book = {title: title.value}

      Meteor.call('add_book', book,
        function(error, id) {
        if (error)
        {
           console.log(error);
        }
        else  {
          title.value = '';
          alert("Does is good:" + id);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

And on Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  add_book: function (data) {

    Booklist.insert(data,function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Meteor.Error(403, Booklist.simpleSchema().namedContext('insertBooklist').invalidKeys()); 
        }
        return res;
      });
 }
});
```

With all this I can put error on console, but for some reason afFieldMessage not shown :\
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to pass an array with list of fields to be invalidated, for example:

```
Booklist.simpleSchema().namedContext('insertBooklist').invalidKeys([{name: 'title', 'type': 'required'}])
```